# Roboearth installation in fuerte in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ros-fuerte, roboearth, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I m trying to install Roboearth from the wiki page but when i try to install ros-fuerte-perception-pcl-addons.
it returns with the error no such package found.
Is there some other way to install these depedencies?

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33645/roboearth-installation-in-fuerte-in-ubuntu-12.04/) by [pntripathi9417](https://answers.ros.org/users/1369/pntripathi9417/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-06-18**:
Same for me on 11.10, that package does not seem to exist on fuerte or unstable. Found it in [trunk](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/perception_pcl_addons/trunk/) and tried to compile, but its dependencies and the requirements of their dependencies again are too old and tangled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please try it again. It should compile under ROS Fuerte now.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-06-20**:
So far I got everything compiled, thanks for your work!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also want to install roboearth on ubuntu12.04 ros fuerte. Can you put more detail step and website?

---

Originally posted by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) with karma: 287 on 2012-06-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1